# How to change the gedit “Highlight current line”color?

Tags: gedit, colors

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10-gnome3.14. Here is the question. when I check the "highlight current line" check-box on the gedit, it highlight the current line, but the color is pure white I can barely see the code. So, how can I change this.

I don't mean to change the syntax highlight style, just change the "highlight current line" color.

Answer (score 11):

I have 14.04, but `gedit` over there has an option to change color scheme --- the preferences menu is quite hidden (at least in gnome-shell), you have to go on the panel menu to find it:

[image: finding the preference menu entry]

(will be different in Unity), and then:

[image: change color scheme in gedit]

and all your color scheme will change. In the shot above, I choose "kate".

If you want to change just the color of the highlight line (for example), you should edit the style; *in principle* that should be easily done by changing the file

```
/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/kate.xml
```

(reference [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/)) and change the line

```
<style name="current-line"                background="#EEF6FF"/>
```

to your liking. Unfortunately, **it doesn't work** --- if anyone know why please chime in.

Comment: My XFCE had styles in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/` and also `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/styles/`, for whatever reason it was using the `2.0` ones as the "defaults", and it wouldn't change them unless I added the just-edited `kate.xml` file (it wouldn't make a new Kate entry, but put the new one "on top of" the old one). And deleting the "new" Kate worked too, so it would re-read the old file & "reset" kate... kind of finicky.

Comment: Hi,Thx all above.
Im using gedit3.14,so I don't have the GUI to change the color scheme from the gedit Preferences. But Rmano, u inspired me, so I changed the color scheme from the dconf-editor. But, when I wrote my own xml scheme file and put it into /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/, it didn't work,even when I deleted the system default scheme xmls in /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/, I still can use the kate oblivion...scheme etc. And not like Xen2050, I don't have the/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/styles/ folder,so my gedit is must using the scheme xml from somewhere else, Please Help

Comment: @SethLee, I too have just the 3.0 version and `gedit` ignores me completely. Finding the preferences was complex --- I use gnome and you can only find them under the panel menu (will add a shot). But if this another configurability that gnome decided to take away, my only solution is to change to another editor, as I did (using `vim`/`gvim` now, but `kate` or `geany` are quite good too).

Comment: @Rmano, Thx, last time I replied u, the first picture u sent is broken, it finally appeared this time, so I ve found the preference option. But the new question is I change the xml file in the /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/ but it didn't work, and when I want to add my own scheme through the Preference Font&Color and it replied that "The selected color scheme cannot be installed". what's wrong with it？ could u help my ^_^.

Comment: @SethLee, as I said in the answer, it neither works for me --- I don't know why. It really smell as a bug to me; feel free to [report it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: @Rmano Hi, I still don't know to add my own scheme by edit xml file, but I find another way to add and use ur own scheme.

    1.open Ubuntu Software Center, search gedit
    2.add optional add-ons "A Set of gedit plugins for developers"&"set of plugins for gedit"
    3.enable the add-ons from gedit preference, especially "Color Scheme Editor"
    4.edit ur own color scheme for gedit and save.
    all done.
So, if u want use  your own scheme, try this.^_^

Answer (score 1):

I've already find a way to solve this problem.

```
1.open Ubuntu Software Center, search gedit
2.add optional add-ons "A Set of gedit plugins for developers"&"set of plugins for gedit"
3.enable the add-ons from gedit preference, especially "Color Scheme Editor"
4.edit ur own color scheme for gedit and save.
all done.
```

but there is still a question: I search the /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/ folder, can not find my own scheme file that I just create. Where did the system store the scheme file for gedit???

Comment: You can try do a full search of the file system with `find / -name "yourschemename*" -print`... it should print something.